# Allocated virtual memory is not accepted by NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans7.0

I'm doing project in NetBeans IDE 7.0.1. I need a lot of Virtual memory for my project nearly 4 GB.I have set Virtual memory for my project upto 1.5 GB and it is accepted for 20,00,000 chromosomes to store.My laptop is having RAM 3GB. I have customize it to 5 GB using Hard disk memory.But I need 4 GB virtual memory to store 50,00,000. The following statement is displayed when I run my project,

run:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```